# Has many through query using the date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause, to-date

I am trying to use the value from a has_many :through relationship to retrieve a list of Authors but my logic is failing.

What would be the best way to achieve this

Currently trying this without success

```rb
start_date = '01/01/0001'.to_date.beginning_of_day
end_date = '01/01/2020'.to_date.end_of_day

Author.includes(:books).where("date(books.release_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date, end_date)
```

I can retrieve just the books by using

```rb
Book.where("date(release_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date, end_date)
```

But want to get this query above working

Comment: try `joins` instead of `includes` ... should work

Answer (score 1):

Your query is likely failing because you are using `includes` with a SQL string fragment. Rails does not infer any associations on `includes` using SQL strings, so [references](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references) must be used in conjunction:

```
Author.includes(:books).references(:books).where("date(books.release_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date, end_date)
```

Alternatively, you can use the query DSL to construct the same where clause and Rails will be able to infer the association:

```
Author.includes(:books).where({ books: { release_date: 1.year.ago..Time.now } })
```

If you're just trying to filter down to a list of `author`s and don't need the `book`s at all, I'd recommend a subquery:

```
author_ids = Book.where("date(release_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date, end_date).select(:author_id)
Author.where(id: author_ids)
```